Unable to queue a function to a ThreadPool
As the title says, I have been unable to appropriately call the thread queuing function doJob() to assign my output function to a thread in class ThreadPool (code below).  The issue seems to be with the call to std::bind the arguments.  There were several initial errors, including:

C3867: non-standard syntax, use & to create a pointer

So after a few changes, leading to errors, and further changes, my thread call can be represented as this:
int MainDlg::main()
{
    char sendData;
    int packetCount;
    int portNum;
    ThreadPool threads (2);

    //Variables populated here in various ways
        
    threads.doJob(std::bind(&MainDlg::OutputSend, sendData, packetCount, portNum)):    
}    

void MainDlg::OutputSend(char sendData, int packetCount, int portNum)
{
    //Output Stuff        
}

Now the errors I can't shake are:

E30312: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (MainDlg::*)(char sendData, int packetCount, int port), char &, int &, int &>" to "std::function <void (void)>" exists.


C2672: 'std::bind': no matching overloaded function found

I tried to assign the function to a std::function <void (void)> type, but I get the same problem.  According to folks in that other post, this is a pretty elegant and reliable class/solution.  There are answers here that are in the ballpark of a solution to the issues at hand, but I keep circling back to these same errors while implementing other fixes found on SO.  What am I getting wrong?
(Note:  I simplified the code to be question friendly.  doJob is actually being called from a function off the main().
The original code below is from HERE as answered by @David Schwartz:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

class ThreadPool
{
    public:

        ThreadPool (int threads) : shutdown_ (false)
        {
            // Create the specified number of threads
            threads_.reserve (threads);
            for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
                threads_.emplace_back (std::bind (&ThreadPool::threadEntry, this, i));
        }

        ~ThreadPool ()
        {
            {
                // Unblock any threads and tell them to stop
                std::unique_lock <std::mutex> l (lock_);

                shutdown_ = true;
                condVar_.notify_all();
            }

            // Wait for all threads to stop
            std::cerr << "Joining threads" << std::endl;
            for (auto& thread : threads_)
                thread.join();
        }

        void doJob (std::function <void (void)> func)
        {
            // Place a job on the queu and unblock a thread
            std::unique_lock <std::mutex> l (lock_);

            jobs_.emplace (std::move (func));
            condVar_.notify_one();
        }

    protected:

        void threadEntry (int i)
        {
            std::function <void (void)> job;

            while (1)
            {
                {
                    std::unique_lock <std::mutex> l (lock_);

                    while (! shutdown_ && jobs_.empty())
                        condVar_.wait (l);

                    if (jobs_.empty ())
                    {
                        // No jobs to do and we are shutting down
                        std::cerr << "Thread " << i << " terminates" << std::endl;
                        return;
                    }

                    std::cerr << "Thread " << i << " does a job" << std::endl;
                    job = std::move (jobs_.front ());
                    jobs_.pop();
                }

                // Do the job without holding any locks
                job ();
            }
        }

        std::mutex lock_;
        std::condition_variable condVar_;
        bool shutdown_;
        std::queue <std::function <void (void)>> jobs_;
        std::vector <std::thread> threads_;
};


//main() and silly() is really the only actual code not used in the question.

void silly (int n)
{
    // A silly job for demonstration purposes
    std::cerr << "Sleeping for " << n << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds (n));
}

int main()
{
    // Create two threads
    ThreadPool p (2);

    // Assign them 4 jobs
    p.doJob (std::bind (silly, 1));
    p.doJob (std::bind (silly, 2));
    p.doJob (std::bind (silly, 3));
    p.doJob (std::bind (silly, 4));
}


If you want to bind a non-static member function the first argument should be a the object on which the member function should operate. Or use lambda functions, which allow you to express the code you want trivially. The std::function constructor is not accepting your binder because it is ill-formed.

You need to provide the instance of MainDlg, this, as the first parameter to bind. You may find a capturing lambda to be simpler than using bind.

Side note: threads.doJob(std::bind(&MainDlg::OutputSend, sendData, packetCount, portNum)):<- got a colon here, not a semicolon.

In addition to the typo above, you're also opening your function bodies with a }. If you want to provide code snippets, at least try to make them valid. It would've been more helpful here to provide a minimal but complete example of the MainDlg class that could be dropped into the other complete (and working) code example, for purposes of demonstrating your issue.

Since ThreadPool::doJob takes an argument of type std::function, it would be a good idea to call it with an object of type std::function rather than trying to figure out which conversions will get you there.

Just compare the function pointer void (MainDlg::*)(char sendData, int packetCount, int port) with the function pointer void(*)(void) (or in C++, with void(*)()). It's not strange that it won't let you convert the first into the other. Do as @Botje suggested. Pack the call in a lambda: [this,sendData, packetCount, portNum]{ MainDlg::OutputSend(sendData, packetCount, portNum); }.

Here is a hack example with a lambda: threads.doJob([=](){this->OutputSend(sendData, packetCount, portNum);});. But many caveats: The threadpool is scoped by MainDlg::main, so it only exists inside MainDlg::main and will block function exit until all of the jobs complete. That's probably not what you want from a threadpool the long-term.

Bundling this all up with a trivial example, you get: https://godbolt.org/z/4eM59adGe

Apologies for the typos.  I have to copy the code manually since my dev computer must remain offline.  I also seem to have made the simplified code too much so in an insufficient attempt to condense it to stay in scope of the issue.  Thank you all for the effort, and I will implement the suggested changes and return with what's what.  If I have to broaden it to be more true to life I will make the appropriate edits here.

That did it!  You all had it pegged, but @user4581301 's godbolt mockup and example made it clear.  Your line including the lambda did the trick.  Runs like a charm now.
